# TypeScript - Combining multiple interfaces into just one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have few interfaces I want to combine into just only one interface: `Member`:

```
interface Person {
  name?: {
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
  };
  age: number;
  birthdate?: Date;  
}

interface User {
  username: string;
  email: string;
}

interface Player {
  room: number;
  group?: number;
}
```

**My question is:** how can I create a new interface: `Member` by combining the above interfaces, so I end up having the following:

```
interface Member {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number;
  birthdate?: Date;  
  username: string;
  email: string;
  room: number;
  group?: number;
}
```

Please, notice that the structure has changed a bit. For example, fields inside: `Person["name"]` are now included directly on the root level on the new interface. Also, those fields are now mandatory (they were optional before).

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make `Person` interface to a "flaten" interface, let's create new interface called `PersonName`, the new interface will be like:

```
interface PersonName {
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
}
```

then, `Person` interface will come to:

```
interface Person {
  name?: PersonName;
  age: number;
  birthdate?: Date;
}
```

Finally, `Member` interface has been defined with syntax like:

```
interface Member extends Player, User, Omit<Person, 'name'>, PersonName  {}
```

All of code: [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=76&pln=22&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAPwBcamOAcuRANxHJwDmEtIArmQBG0NsUHAoYABYATOJBrIAIvNYEAvgQKhIsRCgCqGaPnZ9jUUhVoYwUUJ1HIIZOMAA2Nuw7abt4aHgkNHc4AE8TQmIoLCwyXgFhKCdOGL4AB0V%20IRENLR1A-ToobBAmClNiGAlbcqovexBHdlDa5kVbRua-Ar1ggFkXJOcAD0gQGQwQ8OgAGmQjOeQAeTJgMAAedBKceYByKwg9gD557dK64jw-BBxbZAocqFpBp%20QAXkrkGLjaAEYAAyzMwWQ60PZ7YHEFxuTzICFQjjcf4AvJAA)

Answer (score 2):

Now `firstName` and `lastName` are mandatory

```
interface Member extends User, Player, Omit<Person, 'name'> {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

[image: firstName and lastName are mandatory]

Answer (score 1):

You can use union of types to create a Member type definition. It will not be an interface. That is it creates an alias to types rather than new type. Yet it clearly shows the origin of the type and its members

```
type Member = Person["name"] & Pick<Person, "age" | "birthdate">
  & User & Player
```

to define the interface you extend those types

```
type T1 = Required<Person> ["name"]
interface Member extends
  T1,
  Pick<Person, "age" | "birthdate">,
  User,
  Player { }
```

another version of the picture is to use exclude construct

```
type T1 = Required<Person> ["name"]
interface Member extends
  T1,
  Pick<Person, Exclude<keyof Person,"name">>,
  User,
  Player { }
```

This allow you to modify propertis of Person and changes will propagate to the Member interface.

To make first and last name mandatory, that is required you mention this

```
type T1 = Required<Required<Person> ["name"]>
```

Comment: how can I make: `firstName` and `lastName` mandatory? they were optional on the original interfaces