# Is it possible to extend an interface inside an object array with React + Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two interfaces:

**Interface 1:**

```
interface ILineItemProps {
    state: 'OPENED' | 'COMPLETED' | 'CANCELLED' | 'PENDING';
}
```

**Interface 2:**

```
interface IProps {
    steps: [
        {
            key: string;
            title: string;
        }
    ];
}
```

Interface 1 must add its object, in this case the state, inside the object of interface 2, thus:

```
[{
key: string;
title: string;
state: interface1
}]

I've tried it in several ways:

[{
key: string;
title: string;
} & Interface1]

Array<{
key: string;
title: string;
} & Interface1>
```

But I could not.

Comment: did you try to push() it? or seperate inside the array with comma instead of `&`?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59134206/typescript-combining-multiple-interfaces-into-just-one) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
interface ILineItemProps {
  state: 'OPENED' | 'COMPLETED' | 'CANCELLED' | 'PENDING';
}

type Step = {
  key: string;
  title: string;
} & ILineItemProps;

interface IProps {
  steps: Step[];
}

// test:

const iProps = {
  steps: [] as Step[],
};

iProps.steps.push({
  key: 'a',
  title: 'b',
  state: 'OPENED',
});
```